# Scale Figure with subfigure

Tags: floats, scaling

I have figure that made of two subfigures, the problem is the figure is larger than my page I want to scale the whole figure to fit into my page (with caption and everything how can I do it)

```
\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{figs/fpr-selected-crop}
        \caption{$fpr$ diagram}
        \label{fig:fpr}
    \vspace{0.7cm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{figs/tpr-selected-crop}
        \caption{$tpr$ diagram}
        \label{fig:tpr}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{XXXXXXXXXXXX}
    \label{fig:fpr-tpr}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Instead of `width=1\columnwidth` in `\includegraphics` use `scale=<dimension>`

Comment: @HarishKumar I want to scale whole figure not subfigure

Comment: Use `\centering\scalebox{0.8}{\begin{subfigure}....\label{fig:fpr-tpr}}`

Comment: @HarishKumar it gave me an error ! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \chapter ...

Comment: Should the subfigures be placed siide-by-side or one above the other?

Comment: @Mico on above the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,scale=0.3}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{$fpr$ diagram}
        \label{fig:fpr}
    \vspace{0.7cm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{$tpr$ diagram}
        \label{fig:tpr}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{XXXXXXXXXXXX}
    \label{fig:fpr-tpr}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust `scale` value as you wish.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of scaling the graphs *twice* -- first relative to the *width* of the textblock and second to make the entire `figure` fit inside the textblock -- you may want to scale the graphs directly relative to the *height* of the textblock. 
The advantage of this approach is that the font size of the captions doesn't have be shrunk.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show textblock boundaries
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.42\textheight]{figs/fpr-selected-crop}
        \caption{$fpr$ diagram}
        \label{fig:fpr}
    \vspace{0.06\textheight}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.42\textheight]{figs/tpr-selected-crop}
        \caption{$tpr$ diagram}
        \label{fig:tpr}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{XXXXXXXXXXXX}
    \label{fig:fpr-tpr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```